# How can I access a file in my Grails plugin from a src file in the same plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm working on a JavaScript testing plugin for Grails. I wrote some Groovy classes to perform the testing that I've stored in my src/groovy folder. I hook into the testing events in my plugin's _Events.groovy script and inject an instance of the test runner. From that instance of the test runner, I need to access the JavaScript files, which I've stored in src/js, to perform the testing.

The [plugin documentation](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/12.%20Plug-ins.html) specifies a way to get the path from my Gant scripts, but that doesn't work elsewhere. I've also tried to get access to the `GrailsApplication` via `grailsApplication` or `ApplicationHolder`, but I get `null`. Finally, I've tried accessing `BuildSettings` and `ConfigurationHolder`, but those show me an empty configuration.

To make my plugin work, I am currently copying the JavaScript files into the application's test/resources folder so it's in a known location relative to the working directory, which I'm assuming is the project folder. This feels invasive and fragile to me, so I'd like to figure out a "right" way.

How can I get a path to my plugin from my test runner so I can find those files?

Comment: Instead of copying the files in, now I'm just passing in the plugin location from the _Events script to my test runner's constructor. This way is much cleaner, but still feels contrived to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the BuildSettings and the `pluginManager` bean (either dependency-injected with `def pluginManager` or via PluginManagerHolder) then you can get the path with

```
new File(buildSettings.projectPluginsDir, pluginManager.getPluginPath('foo'))
```

Comment: I can't seem to get an instance of the plugin manager. `PluginManagerHolder.currentPluginManager()` throws an IllegalStateException because there is no plugin manager. I would assume it's because I'm calling this from a file in src instead of something that has a context.

Comment: What's the path of the call - is it during a request, or a new thread? Or from the commandline outside of Gant?

Comment: The call originates in _TestApp.groovy, since it's invoked from `grails test-app`. I hook into the testing events in my plugin's _Events script and inject an instance of my class in src/groovy. I'll add that to the question.